# How to do a scheduled Tile update using locally generated images from background agent?

Tags: windows-phone-8

My scenario is the following:

As soon as background process starts, i want to generate dozens of tile background images using **Deployment.Current.Dispatcher** and then i would like to schedule Tile updates for every background that is generated.

I store all the generated images in **/Shared/ShellContent/** and i am invoking the **ShellTileSchedule** in the following way:

```
var shellTileSchedule1 = new ShellTileSchedule
{
    StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
    RemoteImageUri = new Uri("http://212.120.12.197/wus/shell1.jpg")
};
shellTileSchedule1.Start();
```

However, it seem that **ShellTileSchedule** is not supported by the background process, or at least i wasn't able to find the support here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662941%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Any hint or idea how can i solve my problem?
Regular Tile **Update(ShellTileData)** is not an option as it only runs once every 30 minutes - what i need is custom Tile update several times in 30 minutes period.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update more frequently than the `ShellTileSchedule` allows you must outsource the generation and changing the tile image to a remote service, and use a Tile Push Notification to update the tile when appropriate.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2011/01/03/tutorial-dynamic-tile-push-notification-for-windows-phone-7.aspx) is a good walkthrough.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I can confirm this as a valid answer, since no other mechanism within Windows Phone SDK cannot meet these requirements.